# Populating textbox based on user logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm new to c# and I'm trying to build my skills without using any of the wizard tools (eg. login wizard) provided in .net.  So far I've been successful in creating a very basic login website.

I'm trying to create a user profile page that will display all the data (first name, last name, etc) of the user logged in.

Text boxes on the page should populate on Page_Load but they are not.

here is the aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserProfile.aspx.cs" Inherits="TimeHub2.UserProfile" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="UserProfile" runat="server">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>TimeHub</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">my cards</a></li>
            <li><a href="UserProfile.aspx">profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="">help</a></li>
            <li><asp:Label runat="server" ID="userloggedin"></asp:Label></li>
            <li><asp:button runat="server" id="buttonLogout" text="Log Out" onClick="logOutClick" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="username">username</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="username"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="first_name">first name</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="first_name"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="middle_intial">middle initial</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="middle_intial"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="last_name">last name</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="last_name"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="star">star</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="star"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="rank">rank</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="rank"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="assignment">assignment</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="assignment"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="regular_shift">regular shift</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="regular_shift"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="contact_phone">contact phone</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="contact_phone"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="phone_type">phone type</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="phone_type" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>home</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>cell</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <label for="email">sfpd email</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="email" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="save" Text="update profile" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the c# code I have written to populate the TextBox "first_name":

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //show user logged in
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            userloggedin.Text = Session["New"].ToString();
        }
        //else redirect to login
        else
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection-String);
        SqlDataReader profileReader = null;

        string userDataQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE username ='" + userloggedin.Text + "'";
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(userDataQuery, conn);
        profileReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(profileReader.Read())
        {
            first_name.Text = profileReader["first_name"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does your ASPX page look like?

Comment: I can't find anything that wouldn't work. Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: look at your first line in the while loop.. also I would try casting the data vs using .ToString for example 
`first_name.Text = (string)profileReader["first_name"];`
also where are you assigning the other text fields in your while loop..???

Comment: i've added the aspx code to the question

Comment: I tried casting the data instead of using .ToString, but it threw the following exception:

"An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in TimeHub2.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'."

Comment: try this : `first_name.Text =  profileReader["first_name"]==DBNull.Value ? "": profileReader["first_name"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my own problem.  The issue was in the column names of my database.  my naming convention used underscores in the column names, however I omitted the underscore for the column in question.  Rather than 'first_name' as it should have been, it was 'first name'.

Answer (score 0):

If You are retrieving Only FirstName then There is no need to use `*`

try like this

```
string userDataQuery = "SELECT first_name FROM dbo.users 
WHERE username ='" + userloggedin.Text + "'";

while(profileReader.Read())
{
 first_name.Text = profileReader["first_name"]==DBNull.Value ? "":
 profileReader["first_name"].ToString();
}
```

Beware of SQL Injection Always Use `SqlParameter`

Comment: i plan on using nearly all the data in the row with the exception of 3 or 4 columns.  I just wanted to get one field populated first to make sure I have a working code prior to expanding to all the TextBoxes.

Comment: @StateofDK it will be better if you include name of those 3-4 columns as it will select only some of column from tables